# Perl: Loop over two hashes

Tags: perl

I want to loop over two hashes somehow so that if the keys of Hash A, equal the values of Hash B, then do something:

eg.

```
my $hash1 = {
    'STRING_ID1' => {default => 'Some string'},
    'STRING_ID3' => {default => 'Some string'},
    'STRING_ID5' => {default => 'Some string'},
    'STRING_ID7' => {default => 'Some string'},
};

my $hash2 = {
    content => 'STRING_ID',
    content1 => 'Some text that doesn't equal an ID',
    content2 => 'STRING_ID_5',
    content3 => 'STRING_ID_8',
};
```

if those values are equal, then I want to call a service which gets me a localized string.

The only way I can think of is:

```
while (($key, $value) = each (%hash1, %hash2)) {
    if ($key eq $value) {

        $service->getLocalizedString($key);

    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm not following. The first bit - isn't actually valid perl. Your sample data is too small really to figure out what you actually mean. (a single element hash). Could you spell out more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'll use more sample data, but the point is I want to loop over hash1 and hash2 simultaneously in order to match the key of one with the value of another.

Comment: Added more sample data. I want to match the primary numbered keys of hash 1 with the randomly generated values of hash2.

Comment: If you need to do this repeatedly, consider reversing `hash2` so that its values becomes keys in the new hash.  Then the rest is easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they are hashes, you don't need to use a loop to perform a lookup by key.

```
while (my ($key2,$value2) = each %$hash2) {
    if (exists $hash1->{$value2}) {
        print "($key2,$value2) from \$hash2 ";
        print "matches ($value2,$hash1->{$value2}) from \$hash1\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @snakespan: If that's what you meant, then you should take note of **tripleee's** comment beneath your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, you want to check if %hash1 contains an element with a string replacement, for the identifiers listed in the values in %hash2?

```
while (my ($key,$value) = each(%$hash2)) {
    # check if we have an entry in $hash1
    if (exists $hash1->{$value}) {     
         # call service with the STRING_ID as argument
         $service->getLocalizedString($value);
    } else {
         # nothing found
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the response!

Comment: @snakespan: Do you see how difficult it was to understand your intention? People with low experience are happy to try their hand at answers to stuff like that because they have little to lose, and I am surprised that **mob** felt that he could offer a solution without any further information. For what it's worth, my first guess was the same as **STF's**. Please would you explain (by editing your question) what you meant by stuff like `'STRING_ID1' => {default 'Some string'}`, which doesn't compile?

Comment: I am the Perlnoob Whisperer.

Comment: I've edited the question now so that it at least compiles.